# Setting {silent: true} when resetting a collection still triggers the 'reset' event

Tags: backbone.js, collections, reset, silent

I am trying to reset my collection without triggering the 'reset' event. I have set up my collection to listen to both 'reset' and 'add' events

```
@.listenTo(@options.muses, 'add', @addOne)
@.listenTo(@options.muses, 'reset', @addAll)
```

When I click on a button, the first thing I want to do is to clear out the collection

```
optionButtonClicked: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  target = @$(e.currentTarget)

  //step to clear out the collection
  @options.muses.reset({silent:true})
```

However when I did some logging and checking, I realize that the 'reset' event was still being triggered i.e. the @addAll function was still being called.

Am I missing something here? Isn't silent:true supposed to suppress the reset event?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

reset takes two optional parameters, models 1st, options 2nd. From the docs: `resetcollection.reset([models], [options])`.

so you need to pass in the silent option as the second parameter.

```
@options.muses.reset(undefined, {silent:true});
```